# Monthly/Daily UK Rainfall Data

Tags: data-request, uk, climate

Do you know where I could find UK monthly rainfall data for as many gauges as possible? I am interested in the rainfall daily sum, within one month.

I found this: 
https://data.gov.uk/dataset/historic-monthly-meteorological-station-data

but there are only 37 gauges. Do people know of any resource for the same data but for more gauges?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in rain gauge daily readings or are looking for continuous interpolated surfaces?

Comment: I assume you're familiar with https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/isd and ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ ?

Comment: @BarryCarter - you should post your comment as an answer

Comment: @philshem SE frowns on link-only answers, but if you or someone else wants to post it, that's fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on BarryCarter's [comment](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9930/monthly-daily-uk-rainfall-data#comment13098_9930)

**[Integrated Surface Database](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/isd)** (ISD) from the  National Climatic Data Center (NCDC)

> The Integrated Surface Database (ISD) consists of global hourly and synoptic observations compiled from numerous sources into a single common ASCII format and common data model.

And the data

ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/

[image]